# why doesn't bootstrap have have elements that are 100% width but with max-width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have been playing around with sizing input fields in a fluid bootstrap layout.

To size them you have the input-mini through to input-xxlarge sizes. These result in fields that will overflow their parent container once the container gets too small, so seemingly have problems in a fluid design.

This leaves the spanX sizes and input-block-level classes, which size relative to their parent but have the problem that if the container is too wide then the input is also too wide. The input-block-level makes the input take up 100% of its space.

I've also noticed that the input-block-level class changes the box-sizing to border-box, which results in the input respecting the padding of its surrounding container and not overflowing the container by an amount equal to its internal padding. If you simply set the width of an input box to 100% it will overflow due to its internal padding and the box model.

Anyway, it seems that having a bunch of extra input-mini through to input-large classes, but which instead of having the following style:

```
width: X;
```

have the following style:

```
max-width: X;
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box
```

would be helpful?

It seems like such an obvious thing that people would want because it would enable them to have inputs that don't shrink too large but shrink appropriately when their container gets too small. The reason why I ask here is that being so obvious I'm concerned I must have missed something and there must be some problem with this approach.

Thanks

Comment: This would be more appropriate in a discussion topic, like the goggle group. Make sure you provide a live demo too.